# Include Soap Header - Apache CXF

Tags: soap, soap-client

I have tried adding the header following the Apache CXF Documentation

```
List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
Header dummyHeader = new Header(new QName("uri:org.apache.cxf", "dummy"), "decapitated",
                                new JAXBDataBinding(String.class));
headers.add(dummyHeader);

//server side:
context.getMessageContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);

//client side:
((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);
```

This produces header in the format

```
<SoapHeader>
<dummy xmlns="uri:org.apache.cxf.dummy>decapitated</dummy>
</SoapHeader>
```

what I want to achieve is

```
<SoapHeader>
<dummy xmlns="uri:org.apache.cxf.dummy>
<value>decapitated</value>
</dummy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a SOAPElement and add it to the header, something like this:

```
SOAPFactory sf = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
SOAPElement seqElement = sf.createElement(new QName("uri:org.apache.cxf","dummy"));
SOAPElement textElement = sf.createElement(new QName("uri:org.apache.cxf","value"));
textElement.addTextNode("decapitated");
seqElement.addChildElement(textElement);

SoapHeader dummyHeader = new SoapHeader(new QName("uri:org.apache.cxf","dummy"), seqElement);
```

Comment: in the last we are only adding the seqElelment to the SoapHeader, so the value is still not going to be there

Comment: Solved the Problem                                                                                  
SOAPElement textElement = seqElement.addChildElement("value");

Comment: Forgot about that, added to the answer :)